# XML context default One2many in odoo9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a problem with this xml specification (odoo 9):

> the var "groups_ref" is a Many2many relation with res.groups.

```
<record id="some_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    ....
    <field name="context">{'groups_ref': self.env.ref('security.basic_user')}</field>
    ....
</record>
```

> XML Basic User from module security

```
<record id="basic_user" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">Base User</field>
        <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
   </record>
```

that give me an error :

> NameError: self is not defined

My question is how to pass a default value to One2many relation using this xml definition, I don't want pass it throught field declaration in py. Thanks.

Comment: What about using `ref('security.base_user')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in xml if you want to define a value for a field that need a python expression you need to use `eval`:

let imagine that you have a record in you data base with xmlid = "record_id", so in xml file to define a value of a many2one field to this record :

```
<field name="m2o_field_name" ref="record_id"/>
or
<field name="m2o_field_name" eval="ref('record_id')"/>
```

so in your case try this because i never try it before :

```
<field name="context" eval="{'default_groups_ref':[(4,ref('security.basic_user'))]}" />
```

> note for default value you need to prefix the name fo the field by 
>   < default_ >

Answer (score 0):

Generic syntax for passing group in context

```
<field name="context">{'default_groups_ref': ['module_name.register_group_xml_id_1', 'module_name.register_group_xml_id_2',]}</field>
```

Try with following code:

```
<record id="some_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
....
    <field name="context">{'default_groups_ref': ['security.basic_user']}</field>
....
</record>
```

Comment: The python console error:
`res = self._obj.execute(query,params)`    
`DataError: the entered sintax is invalid for int type: «security.basic_user» Line 10: WHERE "res_groups".id IN ("security.basic_user") ... `

Comment: May you update your question with *basic_user* xml record. Might be problem with record creation.

Comment: Can we use ref in the field ? Cuz' this error is due to the string 'security.basic_user' not being an integer. Integer required for the query WHERE "res_groups".id IN ("security.basic_user") to function. He can't perform that query, he need something like WHERE "res_groups".id IN (1,2).

Comment: Yes we can use that. You may refer these https://git.framasoft.org/framasoft/OCB/blob/dfd298fb8522f52e4bc4f57b30d7b6a06669a24c/addons/account/views/account_invoice_view.xml#L315